# compare 2 string columns in data frame and add 1 to key if different

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out, I have a data frame with multiple columns after merging 2.

```
ID   name_x   name_y   age_x   age_y
1    Steve    Steve    40      40
2    John     John     34      35
```

I have 2 list:

```
list_a = [name_x, age_X]
list_b = [name_y, age_y]
```

I need to compare each group of variables and if they are different add 1 to the key column

```
ID   name_x   name_y   age_x   age_y  key
1    Steve    Steve    40      40     0
2    John     John     34      35     1
```

I was trying to use something like this:

```
for a in list_a:
    for b in list_b:
        master.loc[master[a] != master[b], 'key'] = +1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid loops. Is there any reason we cant do it directly? Lets try

```
df['key'] =(df[list_a].values!=df[list_b].values).sum(1)



    ID name_x name_y  age_x  age_y  key
0   1  Steve  Steve     40     40    0
1   2   John   John     34     35    1
```

Comment: it added up every single comparisson

Key
128
128
128

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: What version are you on and what error did you get? It should work unless the sample you provided does not fully represent you data

Comment: It's not adding the count of discrepancies horizontally, what I'm assuming is doing, is counting the discrepancies vertically by pair of columns, and it's adding to key column

Comment: When 2 columns are empty, it's considered somehow as different and counting it as different.